# How to do case analysis on the length of a list in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am in a situation during a proof where I need to do case analysis on the length of a list `l`.

1. When the `length l < 2` it's one case (in which a binary operation like `+` does not apply)
2. When the `length l >= 2` it's the other case (in which the binary operation applies)

How do I use `destruct` or some other tactic(s) to do this, and obtain two cases, i.e. True and False?

I tried:

```
destruct (length l < 2).

destruct (lt (length l) 2).

remember (length l < 2).
destruct HeqP.
```

But none worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a "constructive" version of `<`, because the standard one is in `Prop`, so you can't perform case analysis on it.
You can either use `compare`, `le_lt_dec` or a boolean version of `<` (search through the doc for all the options, the easiest one should be [this one](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Arith.Compare_dec.html)).

If you really need to test the length against 2, you could also destruct `length n` 3 times and handle by hand the 3 first cases.

Answer (score 2):

Vinz answer is the right one.  When you need to consider two cases that you "know are distinct", it's usually because they are decidable, so look for lemmas that end with `_dec`.  In this case `lt_dec` is defined in `Compare_dec`, and you get it when you import Arith.  So:

```
Require Import Arith.

Goal forall (l:list nat), True.

intro. destruct (lt_dec (length l) 2).
```

Now the first goal is

```
l : list nat
l0 : length l < 2
============================
 True
```

and the second goal is

```
l : list nat
n : ~ length l < 2
============================
 True
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional details.